# How does VS Code Extension call the C ++ dynamic dependency library

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to implement calling C ++ dynamic dependency libraries in VS Code Extension, just like NodeJS uses ffi-napi

Comment: Then what have you tried? An extension is still a Node.JS app.

Comment: thank you,I tried it out with ffi-napi.
What if I want to call a static library now?